# The meaning of “riddle me that”

Tags: meaning, philosophy

In a course of philosophy I heard “I mean it’s not like you’re going to fall asleep already, riddle me that”. My dictionary gives me only the noun’s signification “mystery”. but I guess it is used her as a verb. It’s mean something like “make that mysterious”?

Comment: What did the person who said it have to say?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Riddle me that is an idiom that means:  Go ahead and try to explain that to me.

It trades upon the secondary meaning of *riddle* which is to solve or explain a riddle to someone.  [Link to definition here.](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/riddle)

So essentially when someone says "Riddle me that (or this)" they are saying:

> I find the statement I just made to be puzzling to the point where I consider it to be a riddle.  Go ahead and *try* to explain it to me.

When someone says that, they typically don't expect an answer to be easily forthcoming.

Comment: I'm not quite sure you can really call it an "idiom". OED sense 3 (for the *ponder/puzzle* verb, not the *sift/separate with a sieve* one) has *To solve or answer (a riddle, question, etc.). Also: to solve a riddle **for** (a person).* Essentially, it's just an ordinary construction. To me, an idiom is a form whose meaning can't be directly derived just from the literal dictionary definitions of the individual words.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Riddle me this or Riddle me that are idiomatic in the sense that you use them *en bloc* and in a singular manner that you would rarely use outside of the phrase.  You would say *solve that for me*.  I never hear anyone use riddle in this sense otherwise. Hence, I say idiom.  Perhaps you'd prefer expression . . . but after our last discussion on this, I've found most dictionaries to give them semantic equivalence.

Comment: Well, since I have OED open... **idiom** *3. A form of expression, grammatical construction, phrase, etc., used in a distinctive way in a particular language, dialect, or language variety; spec. a group of words established by usage as having a **meaning not deducible from the meanings of the individual words**.*

Comment: @FumbleFingers I don't deny that it is a known usage.  But, it is more obscure in the sense that it is never used *outside* the expression (making it not *as* deducible).  Hence I've called it an idiom.

Comment: @FumbleFingers And, yes I'm stretching it.

Comment: Note: People usually say _riddle me this_ before stating a conundrum or _riddle me that_ after it.

Comment: @Bradd: In Russian version of [Bonnie and Clyde](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bonnie_and_Clyde) KGB say *"We riddle you **thus**"* as they open fire & riddle the hapless couple with machine-gun fire. (If they'd been up on their Samuel Johnson, they'd have kicked them to death while shouting [*"We **refute** you thus!"*](http://www.samueljohnson.com/refutati.html) :)

Comment: @FumbleFingers I prefer to defenestrate my enemies.

Comment: Bloody [Francophile!](http://english.stackexchange.com/q/155221/2637) I suppose you're a fully paid-up supporter of [Roseanne Barr's campaign to **Bring back the guillotine**](http://www.dailymail.co.uk/news/article-2044747/Roseanne-Barrs-solution-banking-crisis-Bring-guillotine.html), too. (Apparently she's only got the bankers in her sights, but maybe you could slip in a few grammarians as well! :)

Comment: @FumbleFingers No, no, no.  I prefer to throw people out of windows a là [The Defenestrations of Prague](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Defenestrations_of_Prague).  I am NO FRANCOPHILE!

Comment: By the way, did anyone notice that the use of riddle me that in the question was kinda weird?

Comment: @BraddSzonye Yeah . . . philosophers.  Bunch of itinerants running around having their way with the language!

Comment: @Bradd: I've been so busy thinking up snappy comments I didn't pay any attention to the question - which I think is hopelessly Off Topic General Reference *and* a stupid example sentence from a near-illiterate (the source of OP's citation, I mean, not OP himself!)

Comment: @David: Steady on there! Obviously I don't think ***I*** am an idiot, and thanks to Google's better search facilities than the built-in one here, I've been able to identify [a recent usage of my own.](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/151856/does-anyone-know-all-the-meanings-of-should-have-p-p#comment314113_151860) In context, I'm perfectly happy that I made a much better choice opting for *riddle* rather than *answer* - the issue being queried was complex, and more than justified a slightly quirky usage to alert to that fact.

Comment: @David: Admittedly it was more a "slightly whimsical citation" rather than being tchrist's own words as such, but [Riddle me this, Batman](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/107210/2637) obviously wasn't put up there to be ridiculed (effectively, he was *defending* both that and related usages). And without doubt tchrist is one of the most articulate and careful speakers/writers on this site.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I stand humbled by your obvious win here. I will delete my comment post haste.

Comment: @David: Once again, "Steady on!". At the rate you're going, you're obviously learning from ELU faster than me (it took me over 3 years to get this far! :). So pretty soon *I'll* be the one getting outclassed! Seriously, the language looks *vast* at first, but after a while here you do start noticing that *plus ca change...*