# What verb should be used with "puzzles"? We "raise" them, "cast" them, ... or we simply "say" them?

Tags: single-word-requests

What is the right verb for when puzzles are shared with another person? Do we "raise" puzzles? Do we "give" puzzles? Do we "cast" puzzles? ... or do we simply "say" puzzles?

What, for example, can be put in the following blank space?

> In this reality show, they ____ puzzles and participants try to solve them.

I want the puzzle to be in the sentence.

The interesting thing is that the main dictionaries on the web [Cambridge](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/puzzle) [Marriam Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/puzzle) [Oxford](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/puzzle) do not give proper examples to solve this puzzle!

Comment: Perhaps *pose* - a question, a problem, a puzzle: something to answer or solve.

Comment: Well, that's the puzzle, isn't it? **We should buy a bar, and name it puzzles!** https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2pZc00jnvRg

Comment: If you want to ask Hellion a question you have to post your comment underneath his answer. He will not be notified if you mention his username under somebody else's post, unless he himself has also left a comment. And he has left no comments under Tom22's answer.

Comment: "[Riddle me this...](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/155286/45432)"

Comment: Really, you normally just say "told me .." (or, them etc.)  "He told the kids some great puzzles"  "Oh man my brother told me a great puzzle last night."  The fact is that's the most colloquial.  Same as for "story".

Comment: *Set* or *Pose* are the best answers.

Comment: Perhaps the OP should offer a different example: from Sasan's comments below, the primary problem is identifying the actual puzzle. The example Sasan gives implies an embodied authority who is posing an actual formulated (and solvable) puzzle, but the intended use is one where there is no actual puzzle provided, but rather somehow inferred by the solver, and then solved without an authority to certify the answer.

Comment: @Yorik I was suggested to pose the second question that pose by comment as a separate question. Please see: https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/155286/the-meaning-of-riddle-me-that

Answer (score 39, accepted):

The word that first came into my mind when reading your question was *pose*, defined by the [online M-W](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/pose) as (among other things):

> a :  to set forth or offer for attention or consideration let me pose a question

I would say that we *pose* puzzles just like we *pose* questions. However, it depends on context. For example, I would say that

> The mysterious event *presented* the police with a puzzle.

However, if we're referring to one person actively showing another something as a puzzle to be solved, then I would use *pose*:

> I posed a puzzle for my friends to solve.

And if this is somehow obligatory, as in your example of a game show host, if it is a task that must be done, I would use *set*:

> The host sets puzzles for the contestants to solve.

So, for me, *set* is for cases where the puzzle is somehow work to do. Not really for describing something which is puzzling (where *present* would be more common) nor for the action of telling a friend a riddle to solve (where *pose* is more common).

This Google NGram seems to support this interpretation (for what it's worth, this is far from conclusive) with *presents a puzzle* being more common than *poses a puzzle* (the latter is likely mostly used for active cases like my second example above) but *pose a puzzle* being far more common than *present a puzzle* (which has no hits at all) and *set/sets a puzzle* being by far the rarest.

[image: Google NGram comparing pose a puzzle,set a puzzle,propose a puzzle,poses a puzzle,presents a puzzle and sets a puzzle]

The dubious evidence above suggests that *set a puzzle* is far less common than either *present* or *pose*. In the specific example you cite, that of a game show, *set* does indeed work and sounds perfectly natural, but I feel that *setting* puzzles is not as common outside that specific context. Perhaps because *set* carries a connotation of homework. So I would *pose* a puzzle for my friend to solve, but I would *set* a puzzle for a game contestant (who has to solve it in order to proceed) and I would write that a murder *presented* the police with a puzzle.

Comment: What about an example like this: "Our life in this world is somehow like a puzzle. One way to ... such a puzzle is to ask whether it has a purpose at all." I mean examples where we see something as a puzzle in the most general way and then we want to give a more particular form to such a puzzle. The first verb that comes to my mind is "cast". @Neil_UK

Comment: @Sasan please don't take my examples as any sort of "rules". They were just my attempt to formalize the way I would use the words. That said, your example here is quite different. I would fill the blank with *approach* or *look at*. You could *recast* the puzzle in a different way, yes, but not *cast* it.

Comment: "one way to approach such a puzzle" seems to me to mean "one way to see/deal with/understand such a puzzle". But I want to say something like "one way to identify the puzzle" or "one way to put the puzzle in more precise formulation". What about "formulate" or "configure" ? @Neil_UK

Comment: Why do you keep adding `@Neil_UK` at the end of your comments to me? That won't notify Neil since Neil hasn't interacted with this answer in any way. And you seem to be asking a very different question now to what you asked originally. That said, *recast* seems to be what you want for this new question. But please post new questions separately.

Comment: I thought Neil_UK might have something to say about this question as s/he was one of those who answered the original question. That being said, I have bad experience of my question being spotted as duplicate just because of simple similarity.

Comment: OK, but when you use `@username` it only notifies people who have interacted with the post directly (so whoever wrote the post, others who have commented, those who have edited it). Neil hasn't interacted so he won't be notified. You can instead leave him a comment under his answer or under your question and ask him to have a look.

Comment: @Sasan With your new examples, I'm not sure _puzzle_ is the right word. Maybe _riddle_ would be better.

Comment: @Sasan, In the original question you asked about how to describe the act of giving someone a puzzle; in the comments here you are asking about how to describe the act of attempting to solve a puzzle.  Is this a separate question?  Or am I confused about what you intended to ask originally?

Comment: @HarryJohnston No, here my question is not about solving a puzzle. I asked this question separately here: https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/395800/a-verb-for-a-more-precise-way-of-showing-a-puzzle/395839#395839

Comment: Sasan, "Our life in this world is somehow like a puzzle" and so on, are utterly different.  It really confuses things.

Comment: @terdon Thanks for the point. I didn't know that.

Answer (score 40):

The word **present** is frequently used with puzzles

A few ideas:

- perhaps "present puzzles", or
- "present puzzling questions to" (although "puzzling question" is less optimal without additional context as a "puzzling question" frequently means an ill-formed question, but perhaps less so if words like "solve" are used along with it (see below)),
- "present puzzle challenges"

or maybe

- "**challenge** participants with
  puzzles to solve" (challenge could be an alternative to present if
  used this way.

Usually you would couple "present" with "to" or "with":

- "present puzzles to participants for them to solve" or
- "present participants with puzzles"

Comment: "Present a puzzle" often carries connotations that the subject (of the verb "present") is also the source or subject of the puzzle itself. For example, "these data present [us with] a puzzle". If the subject of "present" is a person, it might suggest that the person is themself an enigma.

Comment: Or more generally, "present" implies that the presented is not the author/inventor of the puzzle. Which could be true for the TV show host, but not for the TV show considered as a whole.

Comment: What about an example like this: "Our life in this world is somehow like a puzzle. One way to ... such a puzzle is to ask whether it has a purpose at all." I mean examples where we see something as a puzzle in the most general way and then we want to give a more particular form to such a puzzle. The first verb that comes to my mind is "cast". @Hellion

Comment: @RobinSaunders  I agree, especially with "puzzling questions" which could mean "ill-formed" questions.  I think less so if it is simply "present puzzles to contestants for them to solve"

Comment: My first thought was _show_ but I like _present_ even better.

Answer (score 26):

We set puzzles.

> In this reality show, they set puzzles and participants try to solve them.

This refers strictly to the puzzles. The puzzles are set. Set here has the meaning of 'being constructed or devised', some work has gone in to preparing the puzzle. This is correct using the exact form of the OP's test sentence.

That the participants are expected to solve those puzzles is spelt out explicitly. We do not 'set puzzles to the contestants', though they might be given or presented to them. But that would not use the form of words in the OP.

Amongst the many subtly different meanings of the word 'set' in the OED are 'to prepare', 'to set a trap', and 'to set down on paper', most or all of which are appropriate for a puzzle.

Comment: This is correct. You 'set a puzzle' and 'pose a problem'. And 'propose a solution' (or 'present the correct solution' :).

Comment: I would say that puzzles are "set" in a formal context where participants are required (or expected) to attempt the puzzle, but "posed" when it's an informal invitation to those who might be interested.

Comment: I've just noticed that terdon beat me to this observation (by a matter of minutes!) - and also the observation about "present" - in their answer, which in my opinion is the most comprehensive and should be accepted.

Comment: Hmm. I don't think this is idiomatic in American English, at least not in the Midwest or New England.

Comment: @mattdm well check out my name ;-)

Comment: I'd say that (on a show like Only Connect, for example), the puzzles are *set* by question editors working behind the scenes, and are *posed* by the presenter (Victoria Coren Mitchell, in this case).

Answer (score 2):

I think ***present*** fits the bill for normal usage:

> 6a :  to offer to view :  show
>   b :  to bring to one's attention
>   <sub>*from [m-w.com](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/present)*</sub>

The hosts *present* the puzzles and the contestants try to solve them.

If you *give* someone a puzzle, it implies that the puzzle is a physical object to be examined or manipulated.

(*Cast* is normally associated with a magic spell, not with everyday speech.)

Comment: But "The die/dice is/are cast"

Answer (score 1):

My first thought is that you **construct** a puzzle. I think this is most often used with written puzzles like crosswords, but I think it is used for other kinds of puzzles as well.

Here are a few citations from a quick search around the Internet:

[Douglas Adams](https://web.archive.org/web/20070523005850/http://www.douglasadams.se/stuff/qanda.html):

> So I thought that just for a change I would actually construct a puzzle and see how many people solved.

From a Mental Floss article on [How Crossword Puzzles Are Made](http://mentalfloss.com/article/58828/how-crossword-puzzles-are-made):

> Follow along as I construct a crossword puzzle from start to finish

From a book title:

> [Puzzlecraft: The Ultimate Guide on How to Construct Every Kind of Puzzle](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1402779240)

---

Another option that came to mind would be that you **write** a puzzle (particularly one that's in a textual form).

See that same [Mental Floss article](http://mentalfloss.com/article/58828/how-crossword-puzzles-are-made):

> When I tell people at parties that I write crossword puzzles for a living…

From a [puzzle author's web site](http://www.sutherland-studios.com.au/puzzles/writing-puzzles/):

> There are a few resources out there about writing puzzles. There are very few books out there on how to actually go about writing crosswords, creating find-a-words, drawing mazes and so on. Mostly you have to ‘pull apart’ puzzles and figure out the logic of how they’re done for yourself. The puzzle of how to write puzzles is part of the challenge I enjoy!

Note that that last one also uses the term "creating" and "drawing" for specific kinds of puzzles, but uses "writing" as the general term including them all. If the puzzle isn't presented in a written format, though, then it may not work as well.