# An informal term used for someone who has an affinity for American culture?

Tags: single-word-requests, nouns, adjectives

I came  across the term in an online article, and it  wasn't  "Americanophile"

> : a person who greatly admires or favors America or things from American culture

[Merriam-Webster online](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/Americanophile)

Is there an ***informal term***?

Sample sentence:

> OMG!  He was born in Asia,  and lives  in Asia, but all he eats is hamburgers,; all he watches is American reality TV; and the only music he likes is LA rap. He is such a / so ________________!

Comment: Welcome to EL&U. So this is a word you have heard, just cannot quite remember what it is?

Comment: [Americanophile](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/Americanophile) is the accepted word according to MW. Please update your post with more relevant information. Also, [Single-Word-Requests](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/single-word-requests)  require a sample sentence showing how the target language is used.

Comment: I'm not sure if "identify this word I can't remember" questions are on topic. But if they are, then you should try and provide us with as much detail as possible (just as if you'd asked to have a book or film identified). Where did you see the word? What country was it from? Was it slang, formal, or some kind of jargon? Was it relating to a particular kind of culture (pop culture, music, video games, literature...)?

Comment: "Usonian" is strongly associated with an architectural, furnishing, and  cultural movement that included Frank Lloyd Wright and others of his generation. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Usonia

Comment: Although I appear as an initial  VTCloser, I was in the middle of editing the post to bring it more into line....I think maybe we should re-open.

Comment: NB; F A....you must provide a sample sentence.

Comment: I think this is just a duplicate: [Surely *some* wordsmiths must love America\[ns\]?](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/155221/191178)

Comment: I have provided a sample sentence which I believe works in your Q. If you are unhappy with the edit, feel free to 'roll-back'

Comment: If a Francophile has an affinity for French culture, someone with an affinity for American culture must be a Yankophile. You read it over here first.

Comment: American lover. ha ha

Comment: @Cascabelofmanyzealousepithets  Wiktionary has 'Americophile'.

Answer (score 1):

An Internet slang term that has emerged for a non-American who loves America a little too much is ***freeaboo***. This is a somewhat derogatory snowclone of *[weeaboo](https://www.dictionary.com/e/slang/weeaboo/)*, a term popularized online to refer to a non-Japanese (especially, a non-East Asian) person who is unhealthily obsessed with Japan or Japanese popular culture. This term seems to have displaced the earlier term *[wapanese](https://knowyourmeme.com/memes/weeaboo)*, a portmanteau of "white" and "Japanese," analogous to the more offensive *[wigger](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/wigger)*.

The "free" in *freeaboo* is a play on the habit of certain American hyperpatriots to equate freedom (at least as they conceive it) to the United States itself. George W. Bush used the word frequently in speeches after 9/11, but it truly became a trope in 2003. To protest the French government's opposition to war in Iraq, Rep. Bob Ney (R-OH), chairman of the committee which had power over food service in the Congressional offices, had "French fries" renamed to "freedom fries" on the cafeteria menus.

The move invited a torrent of well-deserved ridicule across the U.S., not to mention abroad, with people jokingly saying things like "freedom kiss" (instead of a [French kiss](https://www.cnn.com/2019/07/06/us/french-kiss-origin-trnd/index.html)). Since then, "freedom" has been ironically and unironically to refer to American exceptionalism and a sort of reflexive (if unproductive) pride in America, like humorously referring to inches and pounds as "[freedom units](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/378090)."

Internet wags have invented an "-aboo" for any number of identities with varying uptake. There are *Koreaboos*, *teaboos*, and *ouiaboos*, and more darkly, *Wehraboos*.

Comment: I was about to downvote as unsupported and probably far from standard, but including (with attribution) the Wiktionary endorsement I found on checking would make this a good answer.

Answer (score 0):

A Yankee Doodle

from [The History of "Yankee Doodle"](https://www.liveabout.com/yankee-doodle-traditional-1322526)

> What would eventually become a patriotic American folk song, actually began with a disparaging term aimed at belittling the might and possibilities inherent in the early American movement. As the colonists started to develop their own culture and government, across the ocean from their British countrymen, some of them no doubt started to feel as though they didn't need the monarchy in order to prosper in the fledgling America. This no doubt seemed ludicrous to folks back home in the heart of one of the world's most powerful empires, and the colonists in America were easy targets for mocking.
>
> But, as has long since become the tradition in the States, those people who were being ridiculed by the slanderous term took ownership of it and metamorphosed the image of the Yankee Doodle into a source of pride and promise.

Sing it, Jimmy! From the lyrics of [Yankee Doodle Boy](https://digitalcommons.conncoll.edu/sheetmusic/1742/):

> I'm a Yankee Doodle Dandy
> A Yankee Doodle, do or die
> A real live nephew of my uncle Sam's
> Born on the Fourth of July
> I've got a Yankee Doodle sweetheart
> She's my Yankee Doodle joy
> Yankee Doodle came to London
> Just to ride the ponies
> I am a Yankee Doodle boy

Comment: Doesn't this just mean "a person who is American" (or more specifically from New England)?

Comment: Yankee Doodle came to town, A-riding on a pony

Answer (score 0):

Another word closely related, but not exactly related to this concept is "ethnocentric".
The Britannica Dictionary definition of ETHNOCENTRICis "having or based on the idea that your own group or culture is better or more important than others"

Answer (score -1):

"**Americanized**", "**enculturated**", or "**assimilated**" all convey the meaning although perhaps not "informally". Very informally (as a colloquialism), "he" has become a "**clone**" (of American pop-culture). Consider the (less than proper) example below.

> He was born in Asia, and lives in Asia, but all he eats is
> hamburgers,; all he watches is American reality TV; and the only music
> he likes is LA rap. He is such a perfect ***Ameri-clone***!

https://www.thefreedictionary.com/clone

Comment: All he eats **are** hamburgers.

Comment: "I will gladly pay you Tuesday for a hamburger today". That was then - this is now. Here's a few more - https://quotesgram.com/wimpy-from-popeye-quotes/

Comment: stereotypes abound.